# Jars in my grails project not being picked up when deployed to tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I am running a grails test run-app all day with my application and it is fine. I type "grails prod war" to get a war, and dump it in the webapps folder of my tomcat install. Now i get the message like so:

```
11.11.2010 16:35:11 *ERROR* GrailsExceptionResolver: Executing action [index] of controller [ResumeController]  caused e
xception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.jaxb.Context (GrailsExceptionResolver.ja
va, line 72)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [index] of controll
er [ResumeController]  caused exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.jaxb.Cont
ext
        at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(JSecurityFilter.java:382)
        at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:180)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
class org.docx4j.jaxb.Context
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.jaxb.Context
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:599)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:199)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:188)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:188)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:169)
        at com.iai.skillsdb.DocxHelpers.DocxParser.openDocx4j(DocxParser.java:70)
        at ResumeController$_closure8.doCall(ResumeController.groovy:164)
        at ResumeController$_closure8.doCall(ResumeController.groovy)
        at ResumeController.invokeMethod(ResumeController.groovy)
        at ResumeController$_closure1.doCall(ResumeController.groovy:41)
        at ResumeController$_closure1.doCall(ResumeController.groovy)
        ... 3 more
```

What is causing this? I have the docx4j jar in my WAR for sure, and it is there in the web-inf lib folder as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, not a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. The class is being loaded, but a class that it depends on (directly or indirectly via another class) isn't there. You're most likely missing a jar that docx4j requires as a dependency.

Comment: Yup, and that's the JAR the questioner's having an issue with in his last question, possibly related to his previous one. - Quite much confusion there, opening three questions for possibly a single issue ...

Comment: Is there a solution that would make grails pull in all necessary jars to the war?

Comment: Yes, use the Ivy configuration options in BuildConfig.groovy. See this blog post for an example: http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/11/04/creating-word-docx-documents-dynamically-from-grails--or-java----.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct version of docx4j and that there is absolutely no other version of docx4j in your classpath, there may be a version of this lib that did not have the 'Content' class implemented.

Comment: this is going on a fresh install of a VM on the server - im the only one using docx4j so it should be fine

Comment: and you are sure that the version of docx4j has a Context class?